# Click Counter not working

Tags: javascript

This is a super basic counter which just counts the button clicks. Below is the body of my html.

```
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper" ><button id="but"> Click</button></div>
    <h2><div class="counter"> Counter: <span id = "countNum"> 0 </span></div></h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var button = document.getElementById('but');
        var counter = document.getElementbyId('countNum');
        var count = 0;
        button.onClick = function() {
            count += 1;
            counter.innerHTML = count;
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

However, there is simply no change on my counter when I click the button. I've tried placing output statements in the start of the script but they don't show up either. Have I placed it wrong? Is it an error with my code?

I've gone through all the similar posts but cannot figure out my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled quite a few functions here.

Here is the correct javascript code.
Please note that its **case sensitive**, i.e. `document.getElementbyId` is not the same as `document.getElementById`, and `button.onClick` is not the same as `button.onclick`.

```
var button = document.getElementById('but');
var counter = document.getElementById('countNum');
var count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
    count += 1;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I had changed the onclick to onClick based on another answer I had read here to no help. My original problem was due to the byId error.